# Странный глюк в программе android связанный с локализацией

Tags: android, locale

У меня в программе есть три языка: английский, русский и украинский. Есть активити на которой у меня висит FloatingButton при нажатии на которую выполняется переход на другое активити. Это не стандартная кнопка, брал я ее с [гитхаба](https://github.com/yavski/fab-speed-dial). У меня там есть два пункта меню, но пока рабочий только один, то есть выполняется действие при нажатии только на один элемент. В кнопке есть менюшка, созданная в папке `menu` и там есть надписи пунктов меню, которые переводятся на три языка при изменении локали. При нажатии на нужный пункт меню осуществляется переход на другую активити. Ниже привожу код слушателя:

```
FabSpeedDial fabSpeedDial = findViewById(R.id.fab_but);
        fabSpeedDial.setMenuListener(new FabSpeedDial.MenuListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareMenu(NavigationMenu navigationMenu) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                if (menuItem.getTitle().equals("Write to your consultant")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MessageCenter.this, WriteResponseMess.class);
                    intent.putExtra("to", 1);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (menuItem.getTitle().equals("Write to some e-mail")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MessageCenter.this, WriteResponseMess.class);
                    intent.putExtra("to", 2);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onMenuClosed() {

            }
        });
```

Что на данный момент получается: выбираем в программе русский язык, все с виду нормально, на всех активити висит русский и все переведено. Менюшка кнопки тоже переведена согласно файлу ресурсов, но при выборе пункта меню кнопки ничего не происходит, хотя должен осуществляться переход на другое активити. Дальше мы выбираем английский язык. Все тоже нормально, перевод везде есть, и кнопка **РАБОТАЕТ**, что означает что при нажатии на нужный элемент меню мы переходим на другое активити. Нормально работает и так как  нужно, а на русском нет. Вот меню кнопки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:title="@string/write_to_your_consultant"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:title="@string/write_to_some_e_mail"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

все строки, которые вызываются в меню переведены на другие языки, и все с переводами нормально.

Вроде как причину я нашел: это поведение появилось после внедрения в программу трёх языков, и соответственно дописались переводы для пунктов меню на кнопке. Попробовал забрать переводы из других языков, и все работает, переходит на другую активити. Не могу понять как решить эту проблему, очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

### UPDATE

вот только-что проверил, то на украинском тоже не работает.

Comment: А что означает "не работает" - догадайтесь сами, да? И как FAB связана с языком - надписи на ней есть? И какая у Вас FAB саппортная или с гитхаба? [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: да протупил немного))) сейчас обновлю вопрос со всей необходимой инфой, простите)

Comment: @woesss, обновил вопрос, вроде дописал все что мог)

Comment: Я так и не Вижу конкретной проблемы. Прочтите свой вопрос сами - что из него можно понять? Вместо "не работает" нужно описать желаемое поведение и что есть сейчас. Если проблема с действием при нажатии, то приложить код обработчика в дополнение.

Comment: я честно говоря в этой ситуации плохо понимаю что именно прикладывать к вопросу, потому-что по логике функции кнопки не должны зависеть от языка интерфейса, или они (функции) все-таки зависят от локали?

Comment: А как же они у Вас не будут зависеть, если title локализован, а Вы сравниваете его с константной строкой на инглише. Используйте `id` для различения айтемов.

Comment: Нужно обрабатывать ``id`` кнопки, а не то, что на ней написано. Язык сменили, надпись поменялась, слушатель не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (menuItem.getTitle().equals("Write to your consultant"))
```

Вы сравниваете локализованный заголовок со строкой на английском - соответственно на других языках условие не может быть верным.
Вместо проверки надписей нужно определять элемент по его `id`:

```
if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.item1)
```

Answer (score 4):

В дополнение к тому, что вместо сравнения текста на кнопке нужно сравнивать `id` кнопки, также вместо `if` можно использовать `switch`:

```
switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.item1:
       // code here
        break;
    case R.id.item2:
        // code here
       break
}
```